# Python dictionary in if else

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

i want to see johns number when i enter his name.
First want to do this:

```
def liste_kontrol(liste):
    liste=raw_input("Name pls:")
    if liste=="john":
        print "now u seeng on list",john,"number."
    else:
        print "cant found"
liste={"john":002050505",} 
liste_kontrol(liste)
```

and perhaps next:

```
def liste_kontrol(liste):
    liste=raw_input("Name pls:")
    if liste=="john" or "jack:
        print "now u seeng on list", john, or jack, "number."
    else:
        print "cant found."
liste= {"john":"002050505","jack":"0551282"}
liste_kontrol(liste)
```

Comment: you got to explain your self

Comment: Go for it! You can do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to do this:

```
def liste_kontrol(liste):
    name=raw_input("Name pls:")
    if name in liste:
        print "now u seeng on list", name, liste[name]
    else:
        print "cant found."
liste= {"john":"002050505","jack":"0551282"}
liste_kontrol(liste)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use exception handling here, and have the look up at the front of the list, try:

```
names = {
    "john": "002050505",
    "jack": "0551282"
}

name = raw_input('Enter a name:')

try:
    print "{}'s number is {}".format(name, names[name])
except KeyError as e:
    print "Couldn't find {}".format(name)
```

This avoids having to program in the valid names as part of the `if` condition, and pre-checking to see if you have a relevant value for a name.

Comment: thank u very much, but i am very new in python, just need to write it for all i know.